# python filtering list for duplicate objects

Tags: python

In the following code am trying to find duplicate objects and assign it to original object list.Is there a optimized way of doing the same

```
user_list = []
unique_user = []
for user in users:
    if user.id not in user_list:
        user_list.(user.id)      
        unique_user.append(user)
    users = unique_user
```

Edit

```
users = [<User {u'username': u'rr', u'name': u'rr', u'enabled': True, u'tenantId': u'81ec14658b764c6799871b9e5573e76f', u'id': u'6bdf7afb1d2e4bd19f7d807063720ac3', u'email': u'r@r.com'}>, <User {u'username': u'rr', u'name': u'rr', u'enabled': True, u'tenantId': u'81ec14658b764c6799871b9e5573e76f', u'id': u'6bdf7afb1d2e4bd19f7d807063720ac3', u'email': u'r@r.com'}>, <User {u'username': u'y', u'name': u'y', u'enabled': True, u'tenantId': u'81ec14658b764c6799871b9e5573e76f', u'id': u'd4afeeb8bc554f2083f93f68638dac0d', u'email': u'y@y.com'}>]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
users = set(users)
```

That turns an iterable into a unordered set of unique elements. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set).

The objects need to be [hashable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.a == other.a
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.a)

set([A(2), A(2), A(1)])
{<__main__.A at 0x2676090>, <__main__.A at 0x2676110>}
```

**Edit:** *How to make them hashable*

```
for user in users:
    user.__eq__ = lambda self, other: self.id == other.id
    user.__hash__ = lambda self: hash(self.id)

unique_users = set(users)

# If you want to remove the attributes to leave them as they were:

unique_users = [delattr(usr, __hash__) for usr in unique_users]
```

Comment: The objects have to be hashable (https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable). You need to define `__hash__` and `__eq__`

Comment: i used set and for the data i have shown.i still have duplicates

Comment: Have you implemented '__eq__' and '__hash__'?

Comment: Nope i cannot implement it since i am fetching users from an external api

Comment: You can monkey-patch them as you fetch them.

Comment: i cannot do a monkey patch now so the reason if i can do it any other way as code in the question

Comment: @Rajeev There is no way Python can know if two objects are equal if you don't tell how to do it. I have edited my answer with a more complete solution, but if you don't modify your objects, there is no better approach than what you have done.

Comment: k sure.Got it,since there is no other go will accept the answer.Thanks for the time